# C++ declaring variable and console

Tags: c++

Please see the image the first *0* is *default*. How to remove it because whenever I input *10* it will show *010* because of the *default 0*
[image]

[image]

Comment: You declare `length` without initializing it and then you do `cout << length`. This is undefined behavior. Initialize your variable before you print it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't post images of text! Copy-paste the text itself into the question body. Images can't be copied by us for testing, and they don't work with screen readers.

Comment: As for your problem, a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) could be useful... Think about the *order* in which you do things!

Comment: uhmm soryy for the rudeness im just a beginner. I want the user to input the the length thats why i put cin >> length but when running the program it has 0 in it (see image 2 ) and i cant erase it. i put 10 and it shows 010 because of the default 0

Comment: Also, local non-static variables (like your variable `length`) are *not* "default 0". They are *uninitialized*, with an *indeterminate* value (that can sometimes be seen as random or garbage).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to print the length before taking an input.
The `cout<<length` will print a garbage value since length hasn't been assigned yet. Try this instead. Also don't use `using namespace std;`

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int length;
    std::cout << "Input length of a square in centimeter ";
    std::cin >> length;
    std::cout << length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Im just studying c++ and it im still in 1 week of learning thats why im using ( using namespace std;)